# Move SQL Server XML column to a new table - slow performance

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a table with a XML Column, each XML document size is 15kb and I have like 2 million rows.

I need to move this XML column into a new table. I tried:

```
insert into newtable 
    select xmlcolumn 
    from originaltable
```

but is taking too long.

Any other way to do it? What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `BCP OUT` and `BULK INSERT` in native mode which will be super fast.

I just tested below script on `[AdventureWorks2008R2].[Production].[ProductModel]` and it work with XML data as well.

Alternatively, you can use SSIS to do it on a more frequent basis if you want.

Below is the script that will help you with BCP OUT and BULK INSERT :

**BCP OUT**

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe" [AdventureWorks2008R2].[Production].[ProductModel] out C:\BCP_OUT\Production_ProductModel.dat -T -E -SSERVER\INSTNCENAME -n
```

**BULK INSERT**

```
BULK INSERT [AdventureWorks2008R2].[Production].[ProductModel_kin] from 'C:\BCP_OUT\Production_ProductModel.dat' 
        with (
        KEEPIDENTITY,
        DATAFILETYPE = 'native',  
        TABLOCK
        )
print 'Bulk insert for Production_ProductModel_kin is done'
```

---

**Whole SCRIPT:**

```
/************************************************************************************************************************************************
Author      :   KIN SHAH    *********************************************************************************************************************
Purpose     :   Move data from one server to another or JUST BCP OUT and BULK INSERT DATA FROM AND IN SQL SERVER !!!*********************************************************************************************
DATE        :   05-28-2013  *********************************************************************************************************************
Version     :   1.0.0   *************************************************************************************************************************
RDBMS       :   MS SQL Server 2008R2 and 2012   *************************************************************************************************
*************************************************************************************************************************************************/

-- save below output in a bat file by executing below in SSMS in TEXT mode
-- clean up: create a bat file with this command --> del D:\BCP_OUT\*.dat 

select '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe" '-- path to BCP.exe
        +  QUOTENAME(DB_NAME())+ '.'                                    -- Current Database
        +  QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID))+'.'            
        +  QUOTENAME(name)  
        +  ' out D:\BCP_OUT\'                                           -- Path where BCP out files will be stored
        +  REPLACE(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id),' ','') + '_' 
        +  REPLACE(name,' ','') 
        + '.dat -T -E -SSERVERNAME\INSTANCE -n'                         -- ServerName, -E will take care of Identity, -n is for Native Format
from sys.tables
where is_ms_shipped = 0 and name <> 'sysdiagrams'                       -- sysdiagrams is classified my MS as UserTable and we dont want it
and schema_name(schema_id) <> 'some_schema_exclude'                     -- Optional to exclude any schema 
order by schema_name(schema_id)                         



--- Execute this on the destination server.database from SSMS.
--- Make sure the change the @Destdbname and the bcp out path as per your environment.

declare @Destdbname sysname
set @Destdbname = 'destination_database_Name'               -- Destination Database Name where you want to Bulk Insert in
select 'BULK INSERT '                                       -- Remember Tables **must** be present on destination Database
        +  QUOTENAME(@Destdbname)+ '.'
        +  QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID))+'.' 
        +  QUOTENAME(name) 
        + ' from ''D:\BCP_OUT\'                             -- Change here for bcp out path
        +  REPLACE(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id),' ','') + '_'
        +  REPLACE(name,' ','') 
        +'.dat'' 
        with (
        KEEPIDENTITY,
        DATAFILETYPE = ''native'',  
        TABLOCK
        )'  + char(10) 
        + 'print ''Bulk insert for '+REPLACE(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id),' ','') + '_'+  REPLACE(name,' ','')+' is done... '''+ char(10)+'go' 
from sys.tables
where is_ms_shipped = 0 and name <> 'sysdiagrams'           -- sysdiagrams is classified my MS as UserTable and we dont want it
and schema_name(schema_id) <> 'some_schema_exclude'         -- Optional to exclude any schema 
order by schema_name(schema_id)
```

Comment: Thanks Kin for the elaborated answer!,  In this case I just want to move data from a xml column, to a new table inside the same database, that's why I was trying to use insert into  with select.

Comment: You can modify the script to do it ..